# SDWebImage's sd_setImageWithURL crashes the application when trying to show 100 of images in view

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, ios8, sdwebimage, didreceivememorywarning

i am showing around 100 of the urls in my one screen asyncronusly in my button image with the SDWebImage.

i am facing issues with the memory load when i tried to show all the images from the url.

i have one UIScrollView and In that i have one UIImageView  which has all the 100 Uibutton Added Dynamaically.

Now my requirement is when user Zoomed int he UIScrollView at certain Level i need to show image in UIbutton and when i start to show the Image from the server to that button with the following code its crashes witht he memory warning.

```
[btn sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:busOwner.WhiteLargeLogoURL] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:placeHolderImage]];
```

can any one please let me know that how can i resolve this memory issues and can also show the images at same time to all the 100 buttons?

i have also tried to put uiiamgeView instead of uiButton and also i have tried to use

```
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            // Perform non main thread operation
            for (BusinessOwnerEntity *busOwner in arrBusOwner) {
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:busOwner.WhiteLargeLogoURL];

                SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

                [manager downloadImageWithURL:url options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

                    NSLog(@"REcieved File %ld",(long)receivedSize);

                } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {

                }];
            }
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // perform main thread operation
            });
        });
```

to download images before but its crashes here too..

Answer (score 1):

Use `SDWebImage` callbacks to load your images in queue, not all at the same time.
It will reduce your memory consumption and avoid iOS to kill your app.

```
[manager downloadImageWithURL:url options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

                NSLog(@"REcieved File %ld",(long)receivedSize);

            } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                       if ("are they less than 10 images loading?"){
                          [self startNewImageLoading];
                       }
            }];
```

Comment: will check it with your logic and let you know..thanks for helping

Comment: its somewhat decrease the memory but not so much..and it still crashes when i try to save the images in document directory with huge memory load

Comment: Reduce the size of your queue. Applies to local saving too. The goal is to stay under the radar for iOS. Make sure to load only the images that are actually on screen or about to be. If you have 100s of images allocated when you can only display 10, you have a serious performance issue. Try to detect when your image is about to appear and load it. And nullify it when it's off screen (after caching it locally). It will use i/o and CPU but will decrease RAM usage.